# Нужно составить в коде нормальный цикл удаления каждого k-го (задаётся с клавиатуры) элемента массива (например, каждого третьего)

Tags: c, указатели

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int* a, i, k, n, j;
    printf("Введите необходимое количество элементов массива:");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    a = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("[%d]=", i);
        scanf_s("%d", (a + i));
    }
    printf("Введите k-ый индекс элементов, которые собираетесь удалять - ");
    scanf_s("%d", &k);
    for (i = 0, j=1; i < n; i ++)
    {
        if (i == k*j-1)
        {
            a[i] = a[i+1];
            ++j;
        }
        n--;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чуть попроще [(пример на ideone)](https://ideone.com/3oyS4d):

```
for (i = 0; i < n - n/k; i ++)
    a[i] = a[i + i/(k-1)];
for (i = 0; i < n - n/k ; i++)
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
```